# how to reconnect to tor network without restarting tor-browser

Tags: networking, tor

Sometimes tor-browser gets slow while loading webpages, I think its the problems of node(s) and needs to be refreshed to get the new node, restarting tor-browser is my way to regain the speed, is not a good idea, how to reconnect to tor network without restarting tor-browser?

Comment: Read this - www.askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Go to `about:preferences#connection`. There you can change Bridge (which will reconnect you).